# How can she use the global variable without passing it in the function argument

Tags: python

Currently in day 15 of Angela's 100 days of python. What I understood from all the exercises and project is that variables outside the function cannot be used inside a function unless it is passed  as an argument or you input "global" inside the function.

```
MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

profit = 0
resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}


def is_resource_sufficient(order_ingredients):
    """Returns True when order can be made, False if ingredients are insufficient."""
    for item in order_ingredients:
        if order_ingredients[item] > resources[item]:
            print(f"​Sorry there is not enough {item}.")
            return False
    return True


def process_coins():
    """Returns the total calculated from coins inserted."""
    print("Please insert coins.")
    total = int(input("how many quarters?: ")) * 0.25
    total += int(input("how many dimes?: ")) * 0.1
    total += int(input("how many nickles?: ")) * 0.05
    total += int(input("how many pennies?: ")) * 0.01
    return total


def is_transaction_successful(money_received, drink_cost):
    """Return True when the payment is accepted, or False if money is insufficient."""
    if money_received >= drink_cost:
        change = round(money_received - drink_cost, 2)
        print(f"Here is ${change} in change.")
        global profit
        profit += drink_cost
        return True
    else:
        print("Sorry that's not enough money. Money refunded.")
        return False


def make_coffee(drink_name, order_ingredients):
    """Deduct the required ingredients from the resources."""
    for item in order_ingredients:
        resources[item] -= order_ingredients[item]
    print(f"Here is your {drink_name} ☕️. Enjoy!")


is_on = True

while is_on:
    choice = input("​What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino): ")
    if choice == "off":
        is_on = False
    elif choice == "report":
        print(f"Water: {resources['water']}ml")
        print(f"Milk: {resources['milk']}ml")
        print(f"Coffee: {resources['coffee']}g")
        print(f"Money: ${profit}")
    else:
        drink = MENU[choice]
        if is_resource_sufficient(drink["ingredients"]):
            payment = process_coins()
            if is_transaction_successful(payment, drink["cost"]):
                make_coffee(choice, drink["ingredients"])
```

I tried to look at her solution and saw that one of her function is using the dictionary resources that is not declared inside the function nor passed as an argument. I am not very good in english that's why I am having a hard time searching in the internet what I specifically want to understand. Can someone enlighten me with this topic please.

NOTE: it is not advised to use global

My code:

(my understanding is that you can never use variables outside the function if it is not either set to global or passed as an argument)

```
def use_resources(user_order, machine_menu, machine_resources):
    """Deduct the resources needed for the user's order and returns the current resources of the machine after the
    user's order. """
    for menu_ingredients_key in machine_menu[user_order]["ingredients"]:
        # print(menu_ingredients_key)  # REPRESENT KEY water, coffee
        # print(menu[order]["ingredients"][menu_ingredients_key])  # REPRESENT VALUES [50,18]

        for resources_key in machine_resources:
            if resources_key == menu_ingredients_key:
                machine_resources[menu_ingredients_key] -= menu[user_order]["ingredients"][menu_ingredients_key]
    print(f"Here is your {user_order} ☕. Enjoy! Come again :)")
```

How can the function use the resources that was declared outside the function and not passed as an argument?

```
def make_coffee(drink_name, order_ingredients):
    """Deduct the required ingredients from the resources."""
    for item in order_ingredients:
        resources[item] -= order_ingredients[item]
    print(f"Here is your {drink_name} ☕️. Enjoy!")
```

Comment: *What I understood from all the exercises and project is that variables outside the function cannot be used inside a function unless it is passed as an argument or you input "global" inside the function.* – that is just not true.

Comment: It helps to write small examples that just show the problem. You could write a small function that uses a global variable then post that instead of this large amount of code.

Comment: You can freely use global variables inside a function, without any explicit `global` declaration, as long as the function only *reads* the variable; in fact, you do this *all the time* in Python (the use of `print()` in that function is another example of the same thing).  Assigning a new value to a variable is what makes it a local variable, unless declared `global`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: @jasonharper I think this is where the confusion starts, in angela's code she is using resources[item] -= order_ingredients[item] , doesnt this mean that she's assigning a new value to the variable?

Comment: @Kejer: no, `resources` is exactly the same object before and after.  Its *contents* have been modified, but that's not what the rule applies to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a simpler example

```
resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}

def test(item, val):
    resources[item] -= val

test("water", 5)
```

This program works. `test` updates `resources` even though `resources` isn't a parameter. Python needs to know which variables used in a function are local and which are not. The rule is simple: variables that are assigned in a function are local to the function. The `global` keyword breaks that rule and lets you assign variables in the global scope.

In this example

```
def test2():
    var1 = "foo"
    print(var2)
    global var3
    var3 = "baz"
```

`var1` is assigned in the function, so python makes it local. `var2` is referenced in the function but is not assigned, so python looks into the global scope for its value. `var3` is assigned, but its also declared `global`, so the local variable rule is broken and the assignment will go to the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

would like to add an answer here posted by John in the udemy QnA section:

Lists and dictionaries are **mutable**. That means that you can add and remove elements from the list/dictionary and it still remains the same list/dictionary object. It is not necessary to create a new list/dictionary in this case.

Almost all other Python objects are **immutable**. That means that once created, they cannot be altered in any way. For example, if a is an integer, then when you do a += 1 ***an entirely new integer object is created.***

Global variables can be read anywhere in the file, including inside functions.

The rule is that ***functions are not allowed to create new global objects*** without you giving specific permission using the global keyword.

To illustrate the point, let's see what the memory location of the object is:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
print(id(my_list), my_list)
my_list += [4]  # my_list is the same list object
print(id(my_list), my_list)
 
print()
 
my_int = 123
print(id(my_int), my_int)
my_int += 1  # my_int is a new integer object
print(id(my_int), my_int)
```

[See Mutable vs Immutable Objects in Python](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747)